# Opposite/inverse of duplicate

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests, subject-verb-inversion

What is a word that can function as the inverse of a duplicate question on Stack Exchange? I was looking, in the context of [this question on meta](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2592/why-can-duplicates-be-marked-as-duplicates), for such a word to distinguish the closed duplicate from the one it was closed as a duplicate of. The relationship is not simply an equal one between duplicate and duplicate, but more like the one between original and copy (where I seek the word for the original). I eventually just coined the word *anti-duplicate*, but a coined word hardly seems a satisfactory solution.

Possible words include:

- Any of *original*, *pattern*, *model*, and *example/exemplar* seem to imply designed similarity. I don't completely understand the nuances of *paradigm*, but it sounds like it belongs in this category as well.
- *Standard*, *ideal*, and *benchmark* come close, but imply official or objective standards, which no question on SE can be. (Can it?)
- *Archetype/archetypical* comes close, but the NOAD under the Usage for "model" says, "An archetype is a perfect and unchanging form that existing things or people can approach but never duplicate." Duplicate questions, however, have approached *and duplicated* the anti-duplicate.
- *Prototype/prototypical* comes close as well, but under the aforementioned usage entry the NOAD says, "a prototype is an early, usually unrefined version of something that later versions reflect but may depart from." The anti-duplicate, in contrast, *is* the refined version, at least in theory, and again, the duplicate has been thus marked because it did *not* depart from the anti-duplicate.

While I seek a different word, I note that if any of the above can be shown to be correct, or if no single word can be found, but a phrase can, either of those will do as well.

Comment: Actually the status quo is that people use either "original" or "dupe". Yes, "dupe" for both the original and the copy. It's usually not that hard to figure out from the context which one they must mean.

Comment: All your examples are excellent and work in the contexts noted. Not much more that anyone else can answer!

Comment: I am an expert of closed questions, but your question, although is still being open, seems quite incomprensible to me. However +1

Comment: possible duplicate of [Word for "the question this one was closed as a dupe of"](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/58141/word-for-the-question-this-one-was-closed-as-a-dupe-of)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Not sure if this helps, but **original** has the [following senses](http://thefreedictionary.com/original).

- Preceding all others in time; first.
- Being the source from which a copy, reproduction, or translation is made.

You say original comes with the notion of "designed similarity", but perhaps we can call a post "original" if it simply precedes the newer one in time.

Comment: As you said, zpletan, "I seek the word for the original". An original can't be designed for similarity because at the time it is made, it is still unique... until its copy is made, of course. +1 from me, the word works just fine for this purpose.

Comment: In light of RegDwight's comment above, I'm marking this as the answer. See also the duplicate question (which is actually the original) above.

Answer (score 3):

Extending a metaphor a bit, you might use **touchstone**. If you put it in quotation marks the first time and explain it, then it should be O.K. to use for your purpose.

**EDIT:** From a purely technical point of view, **[ur](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/ur-)-Question** would be just right... if it weren't a candidate for "world's ugliest word" :)

Answer (score 2):

How about **predecessor**?

(I also like **antecedent**, but it may have connotations of causality that are undesirable.)

Answer (score 1):

Borrowing from math, where you have dividend/divisor and multiplicand*multiplier, how about 'duplicand', where the relationship is duplicand (original) => duplicate (copy).

Answer (score -1):

**Unique**. *adjective* [1.](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/unique) existing as the only one or as the sole example; single; solitary in type or characteristics

> A unique copy of an ancient manuscript.

Comment: Aren't "unique" and "copy" mutually exclusive by definition?

Comment: A copy has adopted the meaning of "a version of a work". Saying that I have the original copy is perfectly understood by everybody who isn't trying to make trouble.

Comment: Yes, if there are multiple copies, having the "original copy" makes perfect sense. But if it's unique... not my downvote by the way (lest you think I'm trying to make trouble), just my observation.