# Why is "proceed" spelt "-ceed" and not "-cede" like "precede"?

Tags: etymology, verbs, orthography

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Origins of the “‑cede/‑seed/‑ceed” suffix](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/21601/origins-of-the-cede-seed-ceed-suffix)

The pronunciation of *proceed* is exactly like that of *precede* with the only difference being the *o* instead of the *e*.

What rules of the English language dictate that it be spelt with the ending *-ceed* instead of *-cede*?

Comment: I think you will find that history oft supersedes any simplistic rule.