# Supercede or Supersede?

Tags: tenses, orthography

I work with thousands of part numbers. Some of the referenced items are now unavailable, and a replacement has been found.

In communicating to my users, do I say 
"x `supercedes` to y" or "x `supersedes` to y" ?

And in discussing the practice, do I term it `supercession` or `supersession` ?

Should I write 'x has been `superceded` to y' or 'x has been `superseded` to y' ?

And then, is it different when referring to it from after the fact, eg: 'y `superceded` x in January' ?

I can't find any answers on this site that address this directly. I have googled it and found conflicting renditions so am no further ahead!

Comment: Also relevant (but not a duplicate): "[Origins of the "-cede/-sede/-ceed" suffix](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/21601/origins-of-the-cede-sede-ceed-suffix)."

Comment: I'm not sure why people are voting to close this question, given that at least some dictionaries accept _supercede_ as a variant of _supersede_. The poster's question about whether one of the two spellings is preferable seems reasonable to me—and Merriam-Webster (at least) doesn't offer any explicit guidance on the point.

Comment: @SvenYargs If the suggestion is that the superceded supercede superceded supersede ( :P ) due to the sit/go split, this leapfrogging might continue. (That's a comment regarding the link you posted, not the VTC.)

Comment: @Lawrence: Now if we could just get a reference to genetically modified crop sources (_superseed_) into your comment, we'd be all set.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As the following Ngram charts indicate, both spellings in each pair have a long history of use, but in each case the *supersede* version is significantly more common than the *supercede* version. Here is the chart for *supercede* (blue line) versus *supersede* (red line) for the period 1680–2008:

[image]

Here is the corresponding chart for *supercession* (blue line) versus *supersession* (red line) for the same period:

> [image]

And here is the one for *superceded* (blue line) versus *superseded* (red line) for the same period:

[image]

As these charts indicate, *supersede/supersession/superseded* remains much more common than *supercede/supercession/superceded* in Google Books search results, even though the frequency of use of the first group of spellings has dropped off considrably from its highest marks around 1850 (for *supersede/superseded*) and 1900 (for *supersession*).

Merriam-Webster's Eleventh Collegiate Dictionary (2003) lists *supercede* as a variant of *supersede*, but historically dictionaries have tended not to look kindly on that spelling, perhaps for reasons of etymology: the *Eleventh Collegiate* traces *supersede* to the prefix *super-* plus the Latin word *sedēre* ("to sit"), whereas it traces *precede* (for example) to the prefix *pre-* (or rather *prae-*) plus the Latin word *cedere* ("to go"). (In case you're wondering, the *Eleventh Collegiate* traces *proceed* to the prefix *pro-* plus *cedere* ("to go"), so the *cede/ceed* split evidently doesn't go back to a distinction in Latin, as the *cede/sede* split does.)

In any event, Merriam-Webster's Collegiate Dictionary series began acknowledging the existence of *supercede* as a variant only in the Eighth Collegiate (1973), which isn't all that long ago in Galapagos tortoise years. I can't think of any reason to prefer that spelling to the longer established, more common, and completely uncontroversial spelling *supersede*.

Answer (score 5):

As explained in the Oxford English Dictionary entry for the term:

> The standard spelling is supersede rather than supercede. The word is derived from the Latin verb supersedere but has been influenced by the presence of other words in English spelled with a c, such as intercede and accede. The c spelling is recorded as early as the 16th century; although still generally regarded as incorrect, it is now entered without comment in some modern dictionaries.

The derivative is listed as "supersession".

You would write "x has been superseded **by** y" and as far as I can tell it's no different when referring to it after the fact. You'd still say "y superseded x in January".